# Can I get subject verb object in string format using NLP in java?

Tags: parsing, nlp, stanford-nlp, part-of-speech

This is sample code:

```
LexicalizedParser lp = **new LexicalizedParser("englishPCFG.ser.gz");**
String[] sent = { "This", "is", "an", "easy", "sentence", "." };
Tree parse = (Tree) lp.apply(Arrays.asList(sent));
parse.pennPrint();
System.out.println();
TreePrint tp = new TreePrint("penn,typedDependenciesCollapsed");
tp.print(parse);
```

For example: "I use a parser" outputs (in Stanford parser)

```
nsubj(use-2, I-1)
root(ROOT-0, use-2)
det(parser-4, a-3)
dobj(use-2, parser-4)
```

But, How can I print subject verb and object without relation.
for example, I want to print

```
subject = I
verb = use
det = a
object = parser
```